# Accept string results in code commenting

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, wininet

I have this snippet from [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233(v=vs.85).aspx)

`lplpszAcceptTypes` - A pointer to a null-terminated array of strings that indicates media types accepted by the client. Here is an example.

`PCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T(“text/*”), NULL};`

The problem here is `/*` in `“text/*”` is read as comment by intellisense and the code which follows this line get commented out. What is the solution here?

Comment: “text/ \ *” I suppose

Comment: Add a comment at the end of the line?

Comment: Hey, my aim is not commenting the code. Aim is to make Accept header to be `"text/*"`

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you use? If I use proper quotes (just straight `"`, not the stylized quotes you copied here), IntelliSense in VS2013 is not at all confused by `/*` appearing in a string literal.

Comment: @SebastianRedl You caught the point. I just copied the stylized quotes from MSDN page. Please add it as an answer so that others can correct this blunder.

Comment: @KarthikNishanth Done. And I'm also going to report it as a bug for the MSDN page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason IntelliSense parses this as a comment is that it isn't a proper string literal. C++ string literals are delimited by simple, straight quotes `"`, but the MSDN example, probably due to being edited in a word processor unsuited to technical content, uses stylized quotes `“` and `”`. These aren't recognized as quotes, so the string literals isn't recognized either, which leads IntelliSense astray. (And it should lead the compiler astray too, if MS has any respect whatsoever for portability.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider this instead:

```
PCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T(“text/” “*”), NULL};
```

The precompilation phase will concatenate the strings transparently and Intellisense will not be confused.

Alternately, you could use a macrodefinition ( I appologize :) ):

```
#define SPLIT_PATH "/"
PCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T(“text” SPLIT_PATH “*”), NULL};
```

... or escaping the string (as @DoomProg suggested in a comment).

Comment: But the curly quotes *that caused the problem in the first place* will still make this not compile ...

Comment: Oh! I thought that the curly quote marks were an artifact caused by copy-paste, not how the code was actually written. :-\